# Pcap library for C# odd problem

Tags: c#, pcap

I'm currently using the PCAP C# library and making no changes from the received packet. The problem is illustrated in the following image.

[http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/6549/wtfisthisshitx.jpg](http://img269.imageshack.us/i/wtfisthisshitx.jpg/)

The left side is Wireshark (The correct version of the captured packet) and the right is my capture using the Pcapсфз library. The c2s do not belong. Has anyone else seen this before?

The code I'm using to receive the packets is almost 100% like the example posted on their website.

Comment: Anything else you need?  Please close your question by marking the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have experience with the library you are currently used [SharpPcap](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/sharppcap/index.php?title=Main_Page) quite extensively and have not had an issue with this.  Alternatively to Pcap, you can use various other products to access packets on the NDIS layer, such as [fireBwall](http://firebwall.com) which uses the WinpkFilter driver.  fireBwall does parse your packets into classes that can be used to reference/change the packet's parsed values.